# JSDoc, documenting an dictionary with default entries

Tags: typescript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

In typescript I can document a dictionary/map that has certain given entries but is still a dictionary/map (as you can add or remove entries) like this

```
type Foo = {
    bar: number;
    moo: number;
    [key: string]: number;
};
```

Is there a JSDoc equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax for params

```
/**
 * @param {Object.<string, number>} foo
 */
```

I'm not sure about using the same with `@typedef`, but guess this one should work too:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object.<string, number>} Foo
 */
```

Type docs http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html

Answer (score 0):

Pure JsDoc

```
/**
* @typedef {{bar: number, moo: number} & Object.<string, number>} Foo
*/
```

JsDoc with TypeScript syntax (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)

```
/**
* @typedef {{ bar: number, moo:number, [key: string]: number }} Foo
*/
```